# Spring Cloud Auth Service Issue (Full authentication is required to access this resource)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, microservices, spring-cloud

I have a problem about creating a user in auth service through api gateway or not.

When I make a request from auth service to `"/authenticate/signup"` , I got the error message named `"Full authentication is required to access this resource"`.

When I make a request to the same url `"/authenticate/signup"` through api gateway, I got a message named `"Could not send request"`.

How can I fix the issue.

Where is the problem in auth service and api gateway?

I implemented this process through jwt token and refresh token.

Here is the project link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/microservicecoursedailybuffer)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
.authorizeRequests(auth -> {
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
          })
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/authenticate/signup","/authenticate/login", "/authenticate/refreshtoken")
          .permitAll()
          .and()
```

> WARNING: If you are configuring WebSecurity to ignore requests, consider using permitAll via HttpSecurity#authorizeHttpRequests instead. See the configure Javadoc for additional details.

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Comment: I get this issue now. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74304377/spring-cloud-api-gateway-jwt-issue-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-xml-b

Comment: I have got another issue related with it in security config in order service or api gateway. Can you look through it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74462679/spring-boot-microservice-security-defined-in-the-service-always-return-403

Comment: Can you look through my another question if you don't mind? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74586470/spring-boot-microservices-spring-cloud-403-forbidden-among-services-control

Comment: I have a similar issue but I cannot fix it. Can you help me if you have any idea about it? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74843944/spring-boot-microservices-rest-template-401-unauthorized-error